# Why is the new keyword not required when hiding a method?

Tags: c#, method-hiding

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254943/what-effect-does-the-new-keyword-have-in-c-sharp-and-why-is-it-only-a-warning):

> The only effect the new keyword has is to remove the warning. The
>   purpose of getting the warning when not using the new keyword is to
>   prevent you from accidentally shadowing the method when you really
>   meant to override it.

But why not simply make it an error? If its intended to prevent accidental hiding, why not go all the way and make it a requirement and not just a warning, so that everything is perfectly clear?

Just to be perfectly clear, I know what the keyword does. Seems like the thought process of the compiler team was 'lets add a keyword because it's good to make things clear, but let's make it optional because it's not really that important to make things clear'...

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, search for "brittle base class"

Comment: @HenkHolterman I appreciate comments, but I can't find what you mean to be the answer. I don't think StackOverflow is intended for "google it" answers (even comments).

Comment: Eric Lippert's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3118480/517852) contains the answer to your question. Basically, you might be hiding because of an edit to a base class that you have no control over.